# Exam class question formatting

Tags: math-mode, exam

Is there any way that I can produce something like this

```
1. \textbf{Subjective Open-Ended} \textit{(1 point)} Is this a question?

2. \textbf{True/False} \textit{(1 point)} Is this another question?
```

[image]

using question environment in the exam class? I want the questions to auto number, have a bold title, italized points, and the question all in the same line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! The [`exam`](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) document class is indeed able to format questions with automatic numbers and point values. If you've gotten stuck somewhere, could you show us what you've tried so far by editing your question with code of your attempts?